# SQL SELECT one virtual Colum with more values

Tags: mysql, select, virtual

I want to creat a virtual Column to do some special operation in MySQL...
So i need to creat a "virtual Column" with some static values. But i dont't know how...

eg. `SELECT 3 as number` shows Column "number" with the value 3.
`SELECT 3, 4, 67, 9` shows four different Columns with only one value.

i tried it with some combination of both, like: 
`SELECT 3, (SELECT 5), (SELECT 4)` or

> SELECT 3 as a, 4 as a, 67 as a

or `SELECT 3 && 6 && 9 && 3` or

> SELECT 3 || 6 || 9 || 3

How my query have to looks like to get only one Column with more values like on a simple statement???

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `union` query to show multiple values within a single alias

```
SELECT 3 as col
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as col
UNION ALL
SELECT 67 as col
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/46877)